# Postgresql - processing exceptions from called procedures

Tags: postgresql, exception, stored-procedures

I have a main procedure (main-procedure) that has exception handling built in.  The main procedure calls another procedure (sub-procedure) that also has exception handling.

In the sub-procedure I raise an exception and I see the error in the console but the main procedure proceeds as if nothing happened.  It even commits the transaction.

I even tried inserting the following code (raise notice '%', 'a'+1) in the sub procedure to see if that would cause the main procedure to stop processing.  I did cause an error but the main procedure proceeded with all remaining steps including committing the transaction.

I searched everywhere for an answer but I was unable to find anything that tells me how to catch exceptions from procedures called within another procedure.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

"Catching an exception" means that you handle the error condition and then proceed normally.  So if you catch an exception in the subprocedure, there won't be any exception in the main procedure, because the error condition is already handled.

If you want the exception to propagate to the main procedure, do **not** handle it in the subprocedure.

It is also possible to handle an error in the subprocedure and then raise it again, so that it propagates to the main procedure.  In PL/pgSQL that would look like

```
BEGIN
   /* code that might throw errors */
EXCEPTION
   WHEN some_error_condition THEN
      /* code to handle the error */
      RAISE;  -- re-throw the same error
END;
```

Comment: Thank you.  That was the issue.  I was raising notice in the subordinate procedure